# Loop through bools and create checkboxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

These are my two classes:

```
public class NotifyUser : ContentPage
    {
       public NotifyUser()
       {
           Namn = "";
           Friends = new List<FriendStatus>();
       }
        public string Namn { get; set; }
        public List<FriendStatus> Friends { get; set; }

    }

   public class FriendStatus
   {
       public FriendStatus()
       {
           Name = "";
           Checked = false;
       }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public bool Checked { get; set; }
   }
```

In my view I try to loop through the NotifyUser-class, displaying the name-property and add an checkboxFor/editorFor the Checked-class:

Here are two ways i´ve tried:

```
@foreach (var friend in Model.Friends)
        {
                @Html.Editor(frien.Name)           
                @Html.EditorFor(frien.Checked)
        }



 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Friends.Count; i++)
        {

                <p>@Model.Friends[i].Name</p>

                @Html.CheckBoxFor(@Model.Friends[i].Checked)
         }
```

Both of these gives me errors, surely there must be a pretty easy way to loop throuhg a list and have a checkbox for a bool?
Thank you

Comment: If you need to post you values/form back to the server, which I think you do, the second method is the correct one, i.e. using `for`. However, without you error message, is hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Yes i need to post the values back to the server, the error in the For-loop is: Argument type "bool" is not assignable to parameter type
system linq expression expressions<system func<notify_core.models.NotifyUser.bool>

Answer (score 7):

The [`CheckBoxFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) extension method expects as parameter an expression which returns `Boolean`. Your example *sets* the `Boolean`. Change it like this instead:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Friends.Count; i++)
{
     <p>@Model.Friends[i].Name</p>

     @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.Friends[i].Checked)
}
```